# Is it possible to use Monotouch.Dialog to create a custom list like this?

Tags: uitableview, user-interface, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, xamarin

I just discovered Xamarin Studio and Monotouch.Dialog, and I've been doing a lot of research on custom table cells. So far I've been pretty successful experimenting with some of the features, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to create something like this: 
[image]

All of the samples I have seen still look like a standard iOS table view, with maybe a few colors changed here and there. My goal is to create truly customized cells, with customized spacing and what not. I'm not sure if this is even possible, so I figured I would ask you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create an OwnerDrawnElement. There's an explanation of this in the Owner-Drawn Element section of this doc:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog

There's also a sample here:

https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements/OwnerDrawnElement.cs